# SQL 2008 Running average with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, moving-average

So i have a table containing below columns.
I want to compute an running average from positiondate and for example 3 days back, grouped on dealno. 
I know how to do with "case by" but problem is that I have around 200 different DealNo so I do not want to write an own case by clause for every deal.

On dealNo 1 it desired output should be Average(149 243 440 + 149 224 446 + 149 243 451)

```
DealNo      PositionDate    MarketValue
    1   |   2016-11-27  |   149 243 440
    2   |   2016-11-27  |   21 496 418
    3   |   2016-11-27  |   32 249 600
    1   |   2016-11-26  |   149 243 446
    2   |   2016-11-26  |   21 496 418
    3   |   2016-11-26  |   32 249 600
    1   |   2016-11-25  |   149 243 451
    3   |   2016-11-25  |   32 249 600
    2   |   2016-11-25  |   21 496 418
    3   |   2016-11-24  |   32 249 600
    1   |   2016-11-24  |   149 225 582
    2   |   2016-11-24  |   21 498 120
    1   |   2016-11-23  |   149 256 867
    2   |   2016-11-23  |   21 504 181
    3   |   2016-11-23  |   32 253 440
    1   |   2016-11-22  |   149 256 873
    2   |   2016-11-22  |   21 506 840
    3   |   2016-11-22  |   32 253 440
    1   |   2016-11-21  |   149 234 535
    2   |   2016-11-21  |   21 509 179
    3   |   2016-11-21  |   32 253 600
```

I tried below script but it was not very effective since my table contains around 300k rows and approx 200 different dealno.
Is there a more effective way to do this in SQL 2008?

```
with cte as (

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by dealno, positiondate desc) as Rownr,
        dealno,
        positiondate,
        Currency,
        MvCleanCcy
  FROM T1
           )

select 
rownr, positiondate, DealNo, Currency,
mvcleanavg30d = (select avg(MvCleanCcy) from cte2 where Rownr between c.Rownr and c.Rownr+3)

 from cte as c
```

Comment: What is `'149 243 440'`?  Is that one number or three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need window functions.  You can do this using `outer apply`:

```
select t1.*, tt1.marketvalue_3day
from t1 outer apply
     (select avg(tt1.marketvalue) as marketvalue_3day
      from (select top 3 tt1.*
            from t1 tt1
            where tt1.deal1 = t1.deal1 and
                  tt1.positiondate <= t1.positiondate
            order by tt1.positiondate desc
           ) tt1
     ) tt1;
```